# VB Copy exited with code 1

Tags: c#

I have a minecraft custom launcher, so problem is whenI try to compile it in VB 2013 i get

> Error 1
>   The command "copy
>   C:\Users\Vuzee\Desktop\MCLauncherNET.git\refs\heads\master
>   C:\Users\Vuzee\Desktop\MCLauncherNET\MCLauncher.net\bin\Debug\commitid.txt"
>   exited with code 1.   MCLauncher.net

So how can i fix it, I googled about it and it says when directory path in not in " "

I have only this copy command:

`File.Copy(file, mcDir + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "bin" + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + Path.GetFileName(file));`

And even when i delete it i get same error, so i dont know what is a problem

Here is full sourcecode of launcher: https://github.com/Digiex/MCLauncher.NET

Comment: I see C#, not VB.net, if you are refering to line number 519 in https://github.com/Digiex/MCLauncher.NET/blob/dd4d874a24f5b668bd27666625ef0c1982f8e86c/MCLauncher.net/MainForm.cs . Also, `File.Copy()` **will** throw an exception if the target filepath already exists, since you don't use the overload which takes a `bool` as a last parameter to allow overwriting (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.file.copy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: You are not yet close to having a problem with File.Copy(), your program has to build properly first.  It can't get a file copied, that's usually because the file is missing.  We can't find it for you.

Comment: so what should i do now, how should i fix it?

Comment: Oh, of course. It was an output from Visual Studio, not from the program.. Make sure you don't have `commitid.txt` open in a texteditor somewhere (also not currently editing it in VS). If in doubt, use something like Process Explorer to find out which process is using the file. After you closed the program which had an open handle on `commitid.txt`, it should compile properly.

Comment: Or the error comes from the file not being found. It looks like it tries to copy some git-related files to the output, which doesn't make sense. Maybe you should delete the .git folder and everything which has to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

**FIXED IT**

**The problem was in prebuild events, there was copy command. I just deleted it and it worked!**